# Ruby command line tool crash when switch ruby version in rvm

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I am trying to make an CLI tool with ruby. 
My tool require some library in bundle (log4r, ...).  So problem appear when i switch my ruby version (2.0.0 -> 2.1.2) or when switch gemset, some gem are not install in new ruby environment.
So how can i make my app work like `vagrant`, which work in every version of ruby i am using?

Comment: Vagrant is a prepackaged application.  It packages it's version of ruby, it's gem dependancies and everything. http://mitchellh.com/abandoning-rubygems

Answer (score 0):

If you package your application as a Gem, you can include a Gemspec that describes your application. One of the things you can specify is [its runtime dependencies](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#add_runtime_dependency); when the user runs `gem install myapp`, then the `gem` command will make sure it includes everything you specified (like log4r).

It will be harder to make this happen without Rubygems. You can package your application along with a defined version of Ruby and all its requirements - [that's what Vagrant does](http://mitchellh.com/abandoning-rubygems) - but that makes your application a larger download and means you have more to maintain. It's going to be hard work if you want to install your app system-wide and have it work with every single Ruby environment. It's far better to let the `gem` application install your app (whether systemwide, or via [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)/[rvm](http://rvm.io/)) and let that manage your dependencies for you. There's the [default gems plugin for rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-default-gems) and [rvm gemsets](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) to help manage this.

Comment: The problem is because i install ruby from rbenv/rvm, my application is available only on this version of ruby and gemset (say 2.1.2, default gemset). All dependency gems like log4r, thor ... install in /Users/guest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2. So if i switch ruby version, my application crash because in new ruby environment, log4r and thor aren't installed

Comment: Yep - but if you're using rbenv/rvm, then your app shouldn't *be available at all* if you switch to an environment without your app. You can use default gemsets with rbenv/rvm that can help you switch between Ruby versions without having to remember to install your app on each - I've added something to my original answer to reflect this.